# Kendo TreeView template text color

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I want to set the treeview to color red if `active='n'` based on the value defined in the datasource field. How to achieve this? [Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OXEZIgEB/2)

```js
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
 // template: "#if(item.active=='n'){# <span style='color:red'></span>  #} #" ,
  dataSource: [
  { text: "Title 1st",  items: [
  { text: "subTitle1", active:"y" },
  { text: "subTitle2", active:"n" },
  { text: "subTitle3", active:"y" },
  ]},{
  text: "Title 2nd"
  }
  ]
});
```

```html
<div id="treeview"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the condition to style attribute in template property as below,

```
template: "<span #if(item.active=='n'){# style='color:red' #} #>#:item.text#</span>"
```

working example [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/@paulrajj/aJurAYeL)

Comment: Hi @Paulraj, I know this thread has been 2 weeks already, I need your help. any idea why it display undefined after I change parents name? https://dojo.telerik.com/aqOtEjIc

Comment: @Nixoderm The property name should be in same name, no matter if its parent or child item. If you would like to use `LedName` then replace all `accName` with `LedName`. Check this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@paulrajj/aLaFavaC)